# Connection of MySQL with Excel - I do not have the option in "Get Data"

Tags: excel, mysql-connector

I have Microsoft 365.

Updated version.

Connectors installed. From https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

But I still do not have the option in "Get Data" - from database - MySQL.

I do not understand why."

I try install everting.
I reinstalled everything, checked all the versions, including connectors, frameworks, and Office, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: which tutorial are you following, what exact steps did you follow

Comment: You can still use the other sources - from ODBC option to use mysql connector. Not really sure what you need to do for a separate option to appear under the from database menu option. From mysql is enabled in my excel, even though mysql connector is not installed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, and sorry for the late response.
I didn't follow any tutorial. It all started when I wanted to connect my MySQL to Power BI. After installing connectors from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/, I was ready to go. Now, I want to do the same with Excel. As referred by @Shadow, I have a friend who has MySQL enabled. So, after some research and calling Microsoft support, the conclusion is based on subscription. If you're a student (university) with a Microsoft account or have Business Premium, you have everything enabled. If not, the common List, from Database' is: "From SQL Server Database","From Microsoft Access Database";"From Analysis Services";"From SQL Server Analysis Services Database (import).